# lt1076 buck boost converter outputting voltage that is too low

Tags: power-supply, switching-regulator, step-down

I am using this buck boost converter from the lt1706 datasheet:
[image: lt1706 Datasheet]

It should take 10 to 40V and output 5V and 2A. But when I proto boarded it it only outputs 2.2V and I really need the 5. I am giving it 16VDC.

Here are the exact parts I used:

1. RL-2444 Renco 0942 100uH inductor
2. lt1076ct switching regulator
3. mbr 340 1410 Schottky diode
4. 200uF capacitor
5. 560uF capacitor
6. 0.01uF capacitor
7. 2.7k resistor
8. 2.21k resistor
9. 2.8k resistor

I'm not sure if one of my parts are wrong, I'm pretty sure everything is connected properly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ah well, *there's* the problem. You're using a NatSemi inductor with a Linear chip :P

Comment: Ok I am totally a newbie here... what does that mean?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. I'm being facetious. The inductor doesn't care.

Comment: oh ok lol. so my inductor is ok?

Comment: Nothing jumps out as being wrong. Inductance sounds right, and it has plenty of current capacity.

Comment: Do you think the fact that I used 560uF capacitor instead of a 500uF capacitor like in the datasheet could be my problem?

Comment: Can you show a photo of your construction? If you can't give a photo, is it done on a breadboard, 2-layer board, 4-layer board, or what?

Comment: It is done on a solderable breadboard.

Comment: No. I doubt its the cap.

Comment: Just to confirm. your circuit schematic has the LT1074 but you are using a LT1706?

Comment: BenG yes, the schematic is from the lt1074/lt1076

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2.21V is the reference voltage, which is just what you are measuring at the output.

I would suspect an open connection on R2 or a short across R1. Measure the voltage right at the feedback pin. If your divider is correct, it should be about 0.97V with 2.2V out.

Comment: Are you going to tell us what it was?

Comment: The capacitor was the wrong value, we ended up using a 470uF instead of 560uF. In fact the 560uF cap blew up when we measured something, idr what we were measuring.